# Will lambda run out of scope if returned

Tags: c++, lambda, scoping

I have a struct which takes a function or callable object as input:

```
struct House {
  std::function<int()> colorSelector;
}
```

Now I assign in this way:

```
House getHouse() {
  House h;
  int color = 10;
  h.colorSelector = [&]() {
    return color;
  }
  return h;
}
```

Will I run into scoping issue? As after getHouse returns, color (local variable) will be destroyed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will I run into scoping issue?

Yes.

Your lambda captures `color` by reference, and after `getHouse` returns, the stack unwinds, and further accesses to `color` are undefined behavior.

You should capture `color` by value to avoid such an issue.

```
h.colorSelector = [color]() {
  return color;
}
```

If you need to refer to the same `color`, perhaps you want to allocate a `std::shared_ptr<color>` somewhere, and capture a copy of that instead.